# Specify the Pods that a Node should run

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, is possible to specify, at the Node level, which deployments it should run? That's kind of different from `Node/PodAffinity`, since would be possible to create a new node with the specified set of deployments running from the beginning, instead of wait for the scheduler to place new pods on that Node.

This would look like templating a VM if you are using some managed Kubernetes service, where you can specify the # of instances and it will be new nodes on your cluster (that will come up with that set of workloads that you defined). Would be that possible or is not the right Kubernetes' mindset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes it's always the scheduler that assigns Pods to nodes. You can't somehow manually launch Pods on a node (outside of Kubernetes) and at the same time let them be a part of the Kubernetes cluster. The way to go is to always define your deployment via the Kubernetes API server and then let the scheduler assign the Pods to the available nodes.

However, you can influence how the scheduler assigns Pods to nodes. In case you want to define at the node level which types of Pods can run on a specific node, you can use [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/): define taints on your nodes and tolerations on your Pods so that only a specific set of Pods can run on a given node.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense... What I'll try to accomplish so is make sure that the pods are placed in different nodes preferably (round-robin the pods thought the cluster) and better resources/limits for each pod.

I wish to say to my managed service that I want 1-5 vms and then say to my pod scale to 5 and be confident that a new machine will be spin up (if not reached the max) and the pod will be placed there. if I have more than 5 vms, so it can schedule the pod to share a node.
And, of course, if I have just 1 pod running, the  number of nodes should be 1

Comment: If you want to do this, you have to write an [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) that implements this logic and is able to add new nodes to the cluster.